# Only get latest results using nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a nHibernate query like this

```
ICriteria query = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MyResult))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("ResultTypeId", myResult.ResultTypeId))
```

Problem is that users add results all the time and I want to show a table of all the latest results for all the diferent ResultTypes I have.

The MyResult class has a property ResultDate. My question is, what do I add to the query to get it to only return the latest result for the given result type. There is nothing to say that the results will be in date order in the database.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question well, Mark wants to see an overview of all the last results for each type.

Which means that, for every result type, he only wants to see only one row, and that is the Result which has last been added for that type.

I think that, the easiest way to achieve this, would be to create an additional class, which we can call 'MyResultOverview' for instance:

```
public class MyResultOverview
{
    public int ResultId {get; set;}
    public int ResultTypeId {get; set;}
    public DateTime ResultDate {get; set;}
}
```

This class should not be mapped, but NHibernate should be aware that this class exists.  Therefore, we'll have to import it:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" >
   <import class="MyResultOverview" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then, we can create an ICriteria which will populate instances of MyResultOverview (and which will also generate the most efficient SQL Query in order to get this overview).
It should look something like this:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCritera (typeof(MyResult));

criteria.SetProjection (Projections.ProjectionList ()
                           .Add (Projections.Property("Id"), "ResultId")
                           .Add (Projections.Property("ResultType"), "ResultType")
                           .Add (Projections.Max("ResultDate"), "ResultDate"));

criteria.SetResultTransformer (Transformers.AliasToBean (typeof(MyResultOverview)));

IList<MyResultOverview> results = criteria.List<MyResultOverview>();
```

This should give you a list of MyResultOverview instances which represent the MyResults that you're looking for.
Then, in order to retrieve the MyResult itself, you can simply do this by retrieving the MyResult instance for that particalur ResultId that you've retrieved as well.

I haven't tested this, nor did i compile it, but this is the path that I would follow to achieve this.

Comment: This was what I was looking for at first but I went with the ordering method. Thanks though, this has helped me understand how to work with projections.

Comment: Just looked at this again. I have used this method to create a query that gives me the max date as a scalar. Then I used this date to filter the main query as I only want results across the latest date.

Comment: I think that using a scalar max date to filter a query giving a collection of MyResults does less SQL than making a collection of MyResultOverViews and then getting the MyResults that correspond. If I'm wrong please put me straight. Thanks for your help anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can order the result by ResultDate using the AddOrder method, as below:

```
ICriteria query = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MyResult))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("ResultTypeId", myResult.ResultTypeId))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("ResultDate"))
        .List<MyResult>();
```

If you want to limit the number of MyResult instances you get back, you can use the SetMaxResults method, like so:

```
ICriteria query = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MyResult))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("ResultTypeId", myResult.ResultTypeId))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("ResultDate"))
        .SetMaxResults(20)
        .List<MyResult>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by `ResultDate` (descending) and select top whatever you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In HQLthis might work:

```
select item, tag
from MyItem item
    join item.Tags tag
where tag.Id = (                                    
    select  max(tag2.Id)  
    from MyItem item2
        join item2.Tags tag2
    where item2.Id = item.Id
    group by item2.Id     
)
```