# How can I make NHibernate aware of a first-class "Null Object", without database persistence?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, null-object-pattern

I would like to make use of the Null Object pattern in my domain, but I don't want to have records in my database that relate to it - I would prefer it if NHibernate were able to map a SQL null value to my Null object, and vice versa.

Is this possible (using Fluent NHibernate for mappings)

P.S. This seems like it is a fairly common issue people are looking to resolve, but I wonder why I have struggled to find an answer.

**Edit:**
Judging by this blog entry it doesn't look like it's going to be directly possible: [NHibernate & Null Object Pattern: The Options](http://journalofasoftwaredev.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/nhibernate-null-object-pattern-the-options/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is... you can't. Oren says "NHibernate's concept of null isn't something that you can easily change, and it doesn't go through an interceptor to do so. You *could* use null objects for value types (using UserType), but not for entities."

Answer (score 1):

In not fluent nhibernate you can use an Import mapping that will not persist to the database like this;

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
      namespace="MyProject.MiddleTier"    
      assembly="MyProject.MiddleTier">
   <import class="ThingNotToPersist"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Don't know how this work in fluent but hopefully it gives you a starter.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite sure how to apply this to the null object pattern though.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I'm not really applying this pattern in the work I'm doing. I use this technique with an ICriteria to get me the latest object from a collection. In the query against a mapped persistent object I use a Projection to get me the latest object, then I use a Treansformer to convert my persistent object into a mapped non persistent equivalent. I can't really go into much more detail, but the help I got for doing this was on here, I'll post a link when I find it.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747382/only-get-latest-results-using-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since this question was posted, NHibernate 3 was released - maybe something is possible now?

I'm not willing to let this go - I want to use the null-object pattern, and I'm not going to be satisfied with "you can't", so let's think about ways to achieve this!

One idea I've come across in several posts and notes around the web, is to use two properties - one with public (unmapped) and one with private (mapped) access - so the get-accessor for the public property would be something like `return MyPrivate ?? MyType.NullObject` ... I've eliminated that idea, because it creates problems with the query interface - you can't query on the public property, because it's not mapped. So we can forget that approach.

I have two ideas I have not seen explored anywhere:

**Use an interceptor to change the property value before/after read/write.**

Someone mentioned an interceptor won't work, but bear with me... in pseudo-code:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public static Bar None;
}

class MyInterceptor
{
    public void AfterLoad(IEntity object)
    {
        foreach (property in object)
            if (property.type == typeof(Bar) && property.value == null)
                object[property].value = Bar.None;
    }

    public void BeforeSave(IEntity object)
    {
        foreach (property in object)
            if (property.type == typeof(Bar) && property.value == Bar.None)
                object[property].value = null;
    }

    public void AfterSave(IEntity object)
    {
        foreach (property in object)
            if (property.type == typeof(Bar) && property.value == null)
                object[property].value = Bar.None;
    }
}
```

In short, substitute nulls with the null-object on load; before saving, substitute null-object with an actual null-value, and after saving, substitute back the null-object.

When using the query API, of course you would need to query for actual null-values, but if you have some sort of criteria-builder or factory-class over the query API, you can account for that there.

**Extend your type to a dedicated null-object type and make it non-persistent. Somehow.**

Just a thought - suppose you were to extend your type into a dedicated null-object-type. Something along the lines of:

```
class Bar
{
    public static NullBar; // instace of NullBar
}

class NullBar : Bar
{
    // ...
}
```

Now that NullBar is a dedicated type extending Bar, can we somehow tell NHibernate NOT to map the Nullar type, even though it extends Bar, which is mapped?

Those are my ideas - either of those sound plausible?

(I'm an NHibernate noob, btw - but I'm persistent, and not in the sense that you can save me and set me aside for later.)