# Select latest group by in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have Canine and CanineHandler objects in my application.  The CanineHandler object has a PersonID (which references a completely different database), an EffectiveDate (which specifies when a handler started with the canine), and a FK reference to the Canine (CanineID).

Given a specific PersonID, I want to find all canines they're currently responsible for.  The (simplified) query I'd use in SQL would be:

```
Select Canine.*
    from Canine
        inner join CanineHandler on(CanineHandler.CanineID=Canine.CanineID)
        inner join 
            (select CanineID,Max(EffectiveDate) MaxEffectiveDate
                from caninehandler
                group by CanineID) as CurrentHandler
            on(CurrentHandler.CanineID=CanineHandler.CanineID
                and CurrentHandler.MaxEffectiveDate=CanineHandler.EffectiveDate)
    where CanineHandler.HandlerPersonID=@PersonID
```

Edit: Added mapping files below:

```
<class name="CanineHandler" table="CanineHandler" schema="dbo">
    <id name="CanineHandlerID" type="Int32">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="EffectiveDate" type="DateTime" precision="16" not-null="true" />
    <property name="HandlerPersonID" type="Int64" precision="19" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Canine" class="Canine" column="CanineID" not-null="true" access="field.camelcase-underscore" />
</class>

<class name="Canine" table="Canine">
    <id name="CanineID" type="Int32">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="String" length="64" not-null="true" />
    ...
    <set name="CanineHandlers" table="CanineHandler" inverse="true" order-by="EffectiveDate desc" cascade="save-update" access="field.camelcase-underscore">
        <key column="CanineID" />
        <one-to-many class="CanineHandler" />
    </set>
    <property name="IsDeleted" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

I haven't tried yet, but I'm guessing I could do this in HQL.  I haven't had to write anything in HQL yet, so I'll have to tackle that eventually anyway, but my question is whether/how I can do this sub-query with the criterion/subqueries objects.

I got as far as creating the following detached criteria:

```
DetachedCriteria effectiveHandlers = DetachedCriteria.For<Canine>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Max("EffectiveDate"),"MaxEffectiveDate")
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("CanineID"),"handledCanineID")
                );
```

but I can't figure out how to do the inner join.  If I do this:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Canine>()
    .CreateCriteria("CanineHandler", "handler", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .List<Canine>();
```

I get an error "could not resolve property: CanineHandler of: OPS.CanineApp.Model.Canine".  Obviously I'm missing something(s) but from the documentation I got the impression that should return a list of Canines that have handlers (possibly with duplicates).  Until I can make this work, adding the subquery isn't going to work...

I've found similar questions, such as [Only get latest results using nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747382/only-get-latest-results-using-nhibernate) but none of the answers really seem to apply with the kind of direct result I'm looking for.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well that's a little bit tough to answer correctly without the mapping - I've solved similar problems by using a subquery - see 14.8. Detached queries and subqueries in the nhibernate reference

Comment: the first query doesn't look quite right - it's won't fetch all current dogs being handled, but the dog that was most recently handled. Multiple results will be returned only when more than one dog was handled starting on the same date.

Comment: The SQL query works. It returns a list of CanineIDs and the date the latest handler was assigned to the dog (i.e. {(1,2010.01.01),(2,2010.03.05),...}. 

The second query matches the handler record by date and dog. I should mention that, in practice, EffectiveDate and CanineID uniquely identify a row in CanineHandler. 

I haven't put an alternate key constraint on that table to enforce this, but even if two rows were returned for a CanineID & Date pair, the query would still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to a derived table, CurrentHandler in your example, won't work in HQL the last time I checked.  Try mapping a stored procedure that lets you write whatever SQL you like.  Here's what a mapped stored procedure looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="S2.BP.NHSupport" namespace="S2.BP.Model">
  <sql-query name="spGoGetMyDogs" callable="true">
    <return-scalar column="PersonID" type="int" />
    exec spGoGetMyDogs @PersonID=:personID
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then you can pass your PersonID parameter in and have NH map the results back to your objects with a transformer like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Canine> LetTheDogsOut(int personID) {
  return nhSession.GetNamedQuery("spGoGetMyDogs")
    .SetInt32("personID", personID)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Canine)))
    .List<Canine>();
}
```

Comment: Looking through the Hibernate documentation, I noticed it has the concept of a natural ID.  That doesn't seem to have moved over to nHibernate.  I tried doing it in HQL and found, as you said, it didn't seem possible.  I ended up just embedding a SQL statement in my repository, but may switch to a SP as you suggested.  Thanks for the response!