# NHibernate with linq paging performance

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate on an SQLite DB in a c# project. I have a generic bulk data processing method that looks like this:

```
    private void DataProcess<Tobj>(int pageSize, Expression<Func<Tobj, bool>> whereClause,
        Action<Tobj, ISession> dataProcessingCallback) where Tobj : IModelBase
    {
        int offset = 0;
        bool moreToGet = true;

        while (moreToGet)
        {
            DataAccess((ISession session) =>
            {
                IEnumerable<Tobj> result = session.Query<Tobj>().Where(whereClause);
                List<Tobj> data = result.Skip(offset)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToList();
                foreach (Tobj item in data) { dataProcessingCallback(item, session); }

                if (data.Count == pageSize) { offset += pageSize; }
                else { moreToGet = false; }
            });
        }
    }
```

(The DataAccess method gives us our session object to work with, handles the transaction, etc.)

Having looked around, this seems pretty similar to most of the other linq paging implementations. They generally do a .Skip().Take()

My problem is that for large data sets (in the test case I'm looking at there are around 200k rows) it takes AGES (about 20 seconds in debugger) to perform the result.Skip(offset).Take(pageSize).ToList(); line. 
This is with pageSize = 100 and offset = 0.

My understanding was that, due to deferred execution, the SELECT wouldn't happen until it needs to (in this case .ToList()). At this point, it knows that which rows it needs to it should only select the relevant 100 rows.

'data' has the expected 100 rows but it seems as if the system has fetched all 200k odd rows from the DB and THEN done the paging in code.

Is my understanding of LINQ/NHibernate incorrect?
If so, I guess I'll need to do something like this with the criteria API: [NHibernate Paging performance (Better option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137356/nhibernate-paging-performance-better-option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following line:

```
IEnumerable<Tobj> result = session.Query<Tobj>().Where(whereClause);
```

You are using an `IEnumerable<Tobj>` field, hence when you invoke `Skip`, you are invoking the [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method. I believe what you want is the [`Queryable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) method.

Try the following line of code instead:

```
IQueryable<Tobj> result = session.Query<Tobj>().Where(whereClause);
```

This will ensure the correct extension method is invoked.

**Explanation**

The [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method will loop over each entity in the source `IEnumerable<Tobj>` and only then return the results after N elements. This will force NHibernate to load all of the data into memory, as NHibernate is only aware that data is required.

The [`Queryable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method will instead build up an expression tree so that NHibernate may handle this later when accessing the data. At that point NHibernate knows to skip the first N records.

Be warned though, I am not sure if the LINQ provider currently supports the `Skip` and `Take` methods.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Thankyou! That makes perfect sense. I made the change and now everything runs perfectly. :)